# Dividindo 1/2 em C#

Tags: c#, .net, matemática, decimal

Em alguns vídeos no *numberphile* sobre o [Zeno's Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?annotation_id=annotation_603899&feature=iv&src_vid=CMP9a2J4Bqw&v=u7Z9UnWOJNY) o professor do vídeo tentava explicar como funcionava esse paradoxo usando as mãos para bater palamas (não sei bem como explicar isso porém vou deixar o vídeo ai na pergunta, assistam o vídeo por favor é mais fácil de entender).

Resumidamente no vídeo é mostrado que toda vez que você vai bater palmas você encurta metade da distância como no exemplo abaixo.

```
1/2 = 0.5
0.5 / 2 = 0.25
```

Para retornar estas divisões pode-se utilizar o seguinte código:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i = 0;
            decimal x = 1m;
            decimal dividir = x / 2m;
            do
            {
                i++;
                Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", i, dividir);
                dividir = dividir / 2m;

            } while (dividir != 0);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

No final são retornados 93 resultados.

Isso está certo?

Não deveria ter bem mais resultados do que isso?

[image: output1]
[image: output2]

Comment: Tentou debugar no 92 e ver qual o valor de dividir?

Comment: Não, é que como isso não é uma calculadora e está longe de ser também na primeira vez que eu executei o programa e fui comparar na calculadora do Windows o resultado da 17° divisão ficou assim. **7,62939453125e-6** e na aplicação está diferente, fiquei pensando sobre isso e acabei nem debugando pra saber o resultado.

Comment: Cada tipo de variável tem uma capacidade máxima em bits. Pegar uma classe com capacidade maior deve aumentar a quantidade de resultados recebidos.

Comment: Pois é, esqueci totalmente disso, bom não totalmente mas enfim, só lendo os comentários e resposta que eu lembrei disso. Obrigado

Comment: @RodolfoOlivieri eu não sugeri você usar o `double` porque eu achei que você queria precisão absoluta. Sim, o `double` fornece números bem maiores porém com desvios. Se isto está ok para você, e está em muitas aplicações, ótimo. Mas saiba  que o resultado não será exatamente igual.

Comment: Esse programinha aí era mais para um teste mesmo, não estou usando em lugar nenhum, apenas para aprendizagem. Quer dizer eu hospedei ele no github mas nada sério

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Está certo, o tipo [`Decimal`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0) tem uma precisão limitada, se você deseja uma precisão maior deverá usar uma outra estrutura ou criar uma específica. Dê uma olha em [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0).

Obviamente o `BigInteger` não resolve seu problema, apenas usei como referência para ver uma estrutura com mais precisão.

```
using static System.Console;
                    
public class Program {
    public static void Main() {
        var dividir = 1m;
        for (var i = 1; dividir != 0; i++) WriteLine($"{i}:{(dividir /= 2m)}");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/tK4FIe). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ruRkEF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Decimal/Division.cs).

Se desejar maior precisão mas com inexatidão pode usar o `double`. Coloquei [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2JxcHs) algumas interações para ver como fica.

Também pode usar alguma biblioteca de `BigDecimal`. Um [exemplo de código pode ser visto no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4524254/221800).

Comment: hmm achei que eu precisaria usar a classe Math, até cheguei a dar uma olhada nela

Comment: `Math` não é bem uma classe, ela é uma coleção de métodos que fazem algumas operações mas não é uma estrutura de dados, ela não resolveria nada. Eu não sei exatamente onde você quer chegar mas tentei pelo menos dirimir sua dúvida principal. Não sei se há alguma intenção de representar algo infinito. Este é um conceito muito abstrato para um computador lidar.

Comment: Era exatamente essa resposta que eu precisava, eu cheguei a pensar que o ´Decimal´ não era grande o suficiente mas por algum motivo não troquei ele para outro teste, obrigado mesmo assim.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente o que acontece é que a última divisão que você consegue antes dele ser == 0 tem uma quantidade de casas DECIMAIS que cabem em um DECIMAL.

Sendo assim o valor que deveria ser para que ele se torne != 0 não cabe no DECIMAL, Logo o valor dividido fica == 0